# Logging caught errors exactly the same as uncaught errors in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, console.log

Let's say I have the following file `error.js`:

```
// this is invalid code
var a: 0;
```

And then in my `main.js` I require that file:

```
require("./error.js");
```

I get a nice, simple, and easy to understand error message from Node.js:

```
$ node main.js
/home/jfischer/error.js:2
var a: 0;
     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jfischer/main.js:1:63)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
```

Now let's try to wrap this in a try/catch block, and print the error by changing `main.js` to:

```
try {
    require("./error.js");
}
catch(err) {
    console.log(err.stack);
}
```

But now we get:

```
$ node main.js
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jfischer/main.js:3:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
```

How can I get the much more human friendly part pointing out the exact file and line of code node broke at in a string?:

```
var a: 0;
     ^
```

---

The [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html) does not appear to expose anything beyond the `stack` property; `message` and `name` are less helpful.

I'm interested for logging errors to files or other custom error logging solutions. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Talk about the timing. First step towards this fix is delivered just two hours ago. https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/4013.

Answer (score 0):

The information is missing when you run the code with Node.js 4, but in Node.js 6 and newer, the helpful information is provided even if the error is caught. Node.js 4 is no longer supported and I imagine by this point you're not using it anymore. But if you or anyone is: Use Node.js 6 or newer and you'll get the information you want.

```
$ nvm use 4
Now using node v4.9.1 (npm v2.15.11)
$ node -v
v4.9.1
$ node main.js
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/trott/temp/main.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
$ nvm use 6
Now using node v6.15.1 (npm v3.10.10)
$ node -v
v6.15.1
$ node main.js
/Users/trott/temp/error.js:2
var a: 0;
     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/trott/temp/main.js:2:1)
$
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Latest node v11 shows every detail even from the imported module.